# Need some idea to get first image path from textarea post value using php [dynamic data]?

Tags: php, html

Need some idea to get first image path from textarea post value using php [dynamic data] ?

When press submit button i will get data like this from `$_POST['textbox']` so i want to get some idea to get first image path from this value.

I tried to thinking for many hours. but i can not do that , how can i do ?

```
<p>
<span style="background-color:" rgb(206,0,0);>Hello</span>
 <span style="text-decoration:" underline;">World</span>
 <img src="https://www.google.co.th/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="width: 544px;">
 <span style="font-style:italic;">Hello</span>
 <span style="font-weight: bold;">World<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/DuncanEdwards1.jpg/100px-DuncanEdwards1.jpg" style="width: 100px;"></span>
<br></p>
```

Comment: Please improve your question by including examples of what you've tried and the results from your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it without a regex would be to use `DOMDocument` in conjunction with `DOMXPath` like this:

```
$str='<p><span style="background-color:" rgb(206,0,0);>Hello</span> <span style="text-decoration:" underline;">World</span> <img src="https://www.google.co.th/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="width: 544px;"> <span style="font-style:italic;">Hello</span> <span style="font-weight: bold;">World<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/DuncanEdwards1.jpg/100px-DuncanEdwards1.jpg" style="width: 100px;"></span><br></p>';

libxml_use_internal_errors( true );

$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->standalone=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->formatOutput=false;
$dom->loadHTML( $str );

libxml_clear_errors();

$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$col=$xp->query('//img');
$images=array();

foreach( $col as $img ) $images[]=$img->getAttribute('src');

echo $images[0];
```

Comment: FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected 'is' (T_STRING) on line number 7

Comment: That exact code runs on my test page ~ to which line on your system does line 7 refer?

Comment: sorry it's work but have 1 issue `Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): error parsing attribute name in Entity` how to fixed it ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing information about how the HTML will be formed, my first thought is to use RegEx to take the first quoted value found after <img